# listening to radio streaming from the web

Tags: php, html, audio-streaming, windows-media-player, internet-radio

I tried to listen to streaming radio from the web by pressing the first result is not a radio voice, is there any error when I enter the url address to the function play_radio. When I click the second button, I managed to listen to the radio but not from windows media player on the web.

Can you help me locate the errors of the function play_radio? Thanks.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play_radio(url)
    {
        '<object style="float: right;" classid="clsid:6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6" width="220" height="50" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701">'+"\n"+   
        '<param name="align" value="center" />'+"\n"+   
        '<param name="url" value="'+url+'" />'+"\n"+   
        '<param name="src" value="'+url+'" /><embed style="float: right;" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="220" height="50" src="'+url+'" url="'+url+'" align="center"></embed></object>'  
    }
</script>
</head>  

<body>
<table style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="10" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="button" value="radio 1" onclick="play_radio('http://www.elshinta.com/v2003a/elsh_streaming.asx')" /></td>
<td><input onclick="window.location.href='http://www.elshinta.com/v2003a/elsh_streaming.asx'" type="BUTTON" value="radio 2" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `play_radio()` function doesn't do anything. It's just a string literal. You have to insert that HTML to somewhere on the page for it to be parsed by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make it output the code, whether the player/object would work as expected, I don't know, but that's the main issue in your code, so you need add document.write or any other way to output that code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function play_radio(url)
    {
        document.write('<object style="float: right;" classid="clsid:6bf52a52-394a-11d3-b153-00c04f79faa6" width="220" height="50" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701">'+"\n"+   
        '<param name="align" value="center" />'+"\n"+   
        '<param name="url" value="'+url+'" />'+"\n"+   
        '<param name="src" value="'+url+'" /><embed style="float: right;" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="220" height="50" src="'+url+'" url="'+url+'" align="center"></embed></object>');
    }
</script>
```